# Android : How can i interface between .java file and GSOAP

Tags: java, android, c++, sqlite, gsoap

I want to send some data using android app to Gsoap server. I am not able to get proper solution. I have created database file in C++ and need to make interface android app with Gsoap c++ file. I am able to connect to gsoap server but unable to store & send data to c++ format **but i want to connect gsoap to .java format**. Can anyone help me out.. or say me how to proceed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cant convert Gsoap to .java file. Its purely used in c language.

Comment: Dear satyam , yes i agree its in c language.I ported the entire gsoap to android and able to run it.the problem i face is ,soap->fconnect(soap,..) always returns -1 .is there any way i can establish the connection ? i totally stuck in this position for almsot 3 days.Any help will be really appreciated and thanks a lot in advance